# ? operator without else-part

Tags: c#, theory, conditional-operator

I use C# ? operator when I have if-statements that affects one row and it's all good. But lets say I have this code (using classic if-statements):

```
if(someStatement)
{
    someBool = true;  //someBools value is unknown
}
else
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

This can be achieved on a one-liner by doing:

```
someBool = (someStatement) ? true : someBool;
```

But why can't I do something like this:

```
someBool = (someStatement) ? true : ;
//or possibly
someBool = (someStatement) ? true;
```

Is this possible in some way? If it is, is there any benefits of using one method over the other? And if not, why shouldn't you be able to do it?

Comment: What do you expect the expressions `(someStatement) ? true : ` and `(someStatement) ? true` to evaluate to?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper true if someStatement is true and unchanged if someStatement is false (this question is purely hypothetical, not an actuall problem I have)

Comment: What is *unchanged*? The expression must evaluate to a concrete value, in this case, of type `bool` - that is, either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper unchanged means that if someBool was true before, then it will still be true. If it was false, then it will still be false.

Comment: Neither the statement `(someStatement) ? true : ` nor the statement `(someStatement) ? true` can possibly know what the value of `someBool` is. They can only return a value based on the input, that is, based exclusively on `someStatement` - or a constant, which is either `true` or `false`. To use your expression syntax in an equally valid context for expressions, imagine this call: `DoSomethingWithBool(someStatement ? true);` - What argument would be passed to `DoSomethingWithBool` if `someStatement` is `false` here?

Comment: @GrantWinney: Actually, the *conditional operator* does not *assign* anything. The *assignment operator* is what *assigns* a value no matter what. The conditional operator *evaluates to a concrete value no matter what (i.e. not an abstract operational instruction such as "leave value unchanged").

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do:

```
someBool = (someStatement) ? true : someBool;
```

I don't think that gains you a lot of clarity over:

```
if (someStatement)
{
    someBool = true;
}
```

But it really seems to be a matter of taste. I wouldn't say either is clearly bad, but the former is uncommon, so I'd probably avoid it.

---

You ask why you can't use the operator like this:

```
someBool = (someStatement) ? true : ;
```

This would be a very big language change! Bear in mind that an assignment looks like this:

```
<location> = <expression>;
```

The expression is evaluated to give some value, and that value is stored in location. (Depending on whether location is a variable, property, field or indexing expression the "storing" operation could be quite different.)

Here you're proposing that the value of the expression on the right, in addition to its normal values, can be a "no-change" value, which has the special behaviour that when you use it in an assignment statement it causes no store operation to occur. That's different from any other normal value, and potentially surprising. But what would it mean if you used it in other places?

```
// Does this call DoSomething when cond is false?
// If so, what value is passed to it?
someObject.DoSomething(cond?x:);

// What happens here if cond is false? Does it cancel
// the entire assignment?
int x = 77 + (cond?2:) * 3 - 4;

// If cond is false, are methods F1 and F2 called or not called?
int x = F1() + (cond?2:) + F2();

// What does this do? Does it skip the return if cond is false?
return (cond?2:);
```

I think you'd find it extremely hard to come up with sensible, intuitive and consistent behaviour for the operator in all these circumstances, and I don't think it would be useful anywhere other than in a simple assignment. It just doesn't fit with the rest of the language - including it would make the language harder to learn, read, understand, implement and explain. It's just not worth it for a tiny bit of conciseness.

Comment: Great answer! Yeah, I hadn't even thought about how it would be implemented in the language

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing a one-liner, i.e. `if (someStatement)  someBool = true; `  ?

Comment: I think @Chucky's answer is far better

Comment: What does this do? Just throws compiler error. Don't see a problem here. Or for example takes the default value. I think it would be convenient to have such single argument ternary operator in some cases

Answer (score 21):

Basically, you're trying to use the conditional operator for something that it's not designed for.

It's not meant to optionally *take some action*... it's meant to evaluate one expression or another, and that be the result of the expression.

If you only want to perform an action when some condition is met, use an `if` statement - that's precisely what it's there for.

In your example, you *could* use:

```
// Renamed someStatement to someCondition for clarity
someBool |= someCondition;
```

or

```
someBool = someCondition ? true : someBool;
```

... in other words "use the existing value unless `someCondition` is true... but personally, I think the original `if` statement is clearer.

Comment: bummer :/ I personally think that the conditional operator is more beautiful.

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson: See my edit for how you *could* use it - but really, it's meant to evaluate an expression. Remember that it's just an expression, *not* a statement.

Comment: yeah, I know, the seccond option is what I use. Was just curious if there were some other way besides that and a normal if-statement

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson: Well you could write an extension method on `bool`, so that you could write `someCondition.MaybeReplace(ref current, newValue)`. But that would be pretty hideous...

Comment: That actually made me chuckle ^^ Hideous indeed

Answer (score 4):

Some background: we use constructs like this a lot:

```
sql = "SELECT x FROM table WHERE Y " + (condition ? " AND Column = 1" : "");
```

We also use constructs like this in Razor views

```
<div class='someclass @(condition ? "anotherclass" : "")'></div>
```

The `: ""` is pretty annoying so we built an extension method

```
public static T Then<T>(this bool value, T result)
{
    return value ? result : default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
<div class='someclass @condition.Then("anotherclass")'></div>
```

taken from [here](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/284-c-ternary-operator-with-no-else/)

Answer (score 0):

*Not the exact same example as the OP's so might not be valid to the specific question.*

*I might not have fully understood the question as it seems more complicated case than my simple use with colors.*

*But for my use case this solution worked.*

*Apologies if it does not solve the OP's specific use case.*

My case was:

```
if ( a ) colorRed;

else if ( b ) colorBlue;

else // no color
```

**[1]**

I first tested:

```
( ( conditionA ) ? colorRed : ( conditionB ) ? colorBlue : false )
```

It throws this error:

`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' and 'bool'    CS0173  247 81`

**[2]**

Testing then as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6208135/10789707

```
( ( conditionA ) ? colorRed : ( conditionB ) ? colorBlue : () )
```

It throws these errors:

`Invalid expression term ')'    CS1525  247 97`

`) expected CS1026  247 100`

**[3]**

Finally tested this:

```
( ( conditionA ) ? colorRed : ( conditionB ) ? colorBlue : null )
```

No error. With needed output.

**[4]**

But I found out the same output is obtained without `null` too for my use case after all.

```
( ( conditionA ) ? colorRed : colorBlue )
```

**[3]** might have some use to some scenarios when the `else` clause does make a difference in the output.