# C# executing code using condition ? method call : method call

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm trying to add to one list or another based on a condition using `? :` syntax, is this possible in c#, the syntax I was using does not compile

```
List<int> Negatives = new List<int>();
List<int> Positives = new List<int>();

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    (number >= 0) ? Negatives.Add(number) : Positives.Add(number);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's for *conditions* to evaluate an *expression*. `Add` has a void type. This is a duplicate - I'll see if I can find one...

Comment: No, its not valid sintax, but you can do `if(number >= 0) Negatives.Add(number) else Positives.Add(number);` in one single line

Comment: Actually, there's more to be said here...

Comment: @Jon #rushingtotypemyanswerbeforeJonSkeet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [?: ?? Operators Instead Of IF|ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208067/operators-instead-of-ifelse)

Comment: I gave up on typing an answer as soon as I saw Jon Skeet's name

Comment: ^ Followed by Eric Lippert. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The conditional operator evaluates one *expression* or other to compute a value. It doesn't execute void-returning methods.

You can use the conditional operator here though, to decide which list to add to:

```
(number >= 0 ? positives : negatives).Add(number);
```

Or more clearly:

```
var listToAddTo = number >= 0 ? positives : negatives;
listToAddTo.Add(number);
```

Of course, you could use LINQ instead, for fun:

```
// This replaces the whole code
var lookup = numbers.ToLookup(x => x >= 0);
var positives = lookup[true].ToList();
var negatives = lookup[false].ToList();
```

Or even, to be more strictly-accurate:

```
var lookup = numbers.ToLookup(Math.Sign);
var positives = lookup[1].ToList();
var zeroes = lookup[0].ToList();
var negatives = lookup[-1].ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The consequence and alternative of a conditional expression must have a value; void-returning methods do not have a value.

Use an `if` statement.

Comment: I'm still weighing this up, but I *think* I prefer the second form in my answer: use the conditional operator to determine which list to add to. I like the way it reduces the duplication, and makes it clear that the adding itself is unconditional - it's only "what it gets added to" that varies.

Comment: Indeed that's not bad.  Even better would be an operator to partition a sequence into equivalence classes. Like, say, group by.